# Django form wizard handling

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-formwizard

I am having a bit of a problem understanding the django form wizard.

Mainly, I don't understand how to handle the form_list.

This is my **view** thus far:

```
class AddLocation(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "dash/AddLocation.html"

    def processAddLocation(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        processAddLocation(form_list)
        return redirect(reverse('location_manager'))
```

And here are my **forms**:

```
class regionForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)


class locationForm(forms.Form):
    location_name = forms.CharField()
    street_address = forms.CharField()
    city = forms.CharField()
    zip_code = forms.CharField()
```

(yes each form is one page of the wizard)

And here is the **model** this form wizard should ultimately be saving as:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street_address = models.TextField(blank=True)  # allowing this blank for the min.
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

1. Now how exactly do I go about handling the form_list?
2. What exactly is the form_list returning?
3. Why do I need a proccessAddLocation method and a done method (this was suggested to me but I can not seem to understand why).
4. How do you save 2 forms to a specific model

Any pointers in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form list is simply a list of the valid forms that the user has completed. Creating a `location` from one form is the same as creating it from many. You just need to make sure you get the data from the correct form's `cleaned_data` dict.

Your `done` method of your view will look something like this:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    region_form, location_form = form_list
    location = Location(
        street_address=location_form.cleaned_data['street_address']
        # populate other fields here
        ...
    )
    location.save()

    return redirect(reverse('location_manager'))
```

You need a `done` method because form wizards require it. You don't need a `processAddLocation` method, so I haven't included it in my answer. You can define this method and move the location creation code into it if you feel it makes the code easier to understand.

In the case of the foreign keys e.g. `region`, you will have to transform the `cleaned_data['region']` into a `region` object. You may have to add validation to your forms to make sure your user enters a valid region. A `ModelChoiceField` may be better for these foreign key fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Few extra questions: If the form_list is more than 2 lists (lets say 3 or more), what is the best way to do assignment for each one? Also, does the form_list come in a list that is the same order that the form was completed? Like form1 is [0] in the list, form2 is [1] etc?

Comment: Yes, the forms in `form_list` are in the order that they were specified in the form wizard. If you have more than two forms, you can continue to unpack them with `form0, form1, form2 = form_list`, or do it on multiple lines e.g. `form0 = form_list[0]`, `form1 = form_list[1]`, and so on.